# How does the Matlab function corr(X,Y) work internally?

Tags: matlab, function, image-processing, correlation, correspondence

I know that the function corr(X,Y) computes the correlation coefficient between pairs of columns in two matrices X and Y. I am having a hard time understanding how this function works under the hood. Could anyone help me to understand what matlab is actually doing once it receives two matrices (what type of math is this function doing)?

Comment: despite that no one but the developers knows what is happening under the hood, they calculate the correlation coefficient of those two matrices X and Y. What is unclear about that?

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is manually write a more simplified function that does the same thing as corr with two input vectors of a single row

Answer (score 2):

The code of `corr.m` is largely accessible. Type `edit corr` at the command line to open the corresponding m-file and to study the function's "inner" workings...

Comment: Thank you! I was never aware this was possible

Comment: Note that you can look at the code of most functions this way. There is a set of built-in functions that for performance reasons are compiled and you cannot see the code, e.g. `sin`.